# Where is the implementation of the GNU C library?

Tags: c, gnu

I'm looking through the glib header files that reside in /usr/include to get a feel for what is going on behind the scenes. All the files I'm looking at simply declare a bunch of macros and functions but I want to take a look at the implementation of these functions.

Comment: Get the glibc-dev package.

Comment: @iccthedral If I need to get them separately then they are not on my machine. How do any of these programs work then if I don't have the implementation of the header files?

Comment: You will have a set of pre-compiled glibc binaries on your system. Those plus the headers are all that are needed to compile & run programs which make use of glibc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The glibc source repository is here:

https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree

Note that **a lot** of the interesting code is under the `sysdeps` directory, particularly `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/*`. Also worth noting is that stdio is split between `stdio-common` and `libio`, and all of the POSIX threads interfaces are implemented under `nptl` (which also has its own `sysdeps` tree.

Further, note that there are a lot of functions for which you will simply not find source code at all. Many of the standard functions are simply entry points for making calls to the kernel (syscalls), and these wrappers are automatically generated as part of the build process.

Comment: So I know that my Ubuntu machine has glibc implemented on it. I'm looking at the kernel tree on kernel.org and don't see where glibc is. So is glibc separate from the kernel? And if so - how can I compile a kernel that implements glibc. I am trying to understand how they interact with each other

Comment: The kernel and glibc are completely separate. I gave you the link for the glibc source tree. The interact with one another via *syscalls*: basically, inline assembly (or an external asm function) in glibc performs a special cpu instruction which transfers execution to the kernel, and the kernel picks up the arguments from the values in registers.

Comment: See also https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/ for a source browser with syntax highlighting and cross links for `#include` and symbol names.  e.g. https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/memchr.S.html

Answer (score 1):

The readable form of the implementation of the functions within the GLibC is contained within its source code, downloadable from [its website](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/download.html).

Note that some of the functions are stubs that delegate to system calls, and the complete implementation will be found within the source code of your operating system.

Comment: Very interesting..thanks for clearing this up for me. Do you know where I can find gLibC in the linux kernel tree